Create a list of nested strings followed by dot from nested yaml
I have an input in yaml with various levels of nested objects. I need a python function to go over it all and get the desired output - list of strings where each field is separated by dot if its nested - Object1.Object2.Object3.Object4... Examples below.
I am trying to achieve it with a recursive function. My code snippet:
tests = []
test2 = {}
def test(config, parent=None):
    previous_parent = None
    names = []
    for column in config:
    
        if column.get("dtype") in ["array", "struct"]:
            parent = column["name"]
            print(f"parent: {parent}")
            test(column["columns"], parent)
            
        else:
            value = column["name"]
            print(f"value: {value}")
            # names.append(value)

And the output is:
value: PartitionDate
value: TransactionID
value: EventTimestamp
parent: ControlTransaction
value: StoreID
parent: RetailTransaction
value: StoreID
value: WorkstationID
...

Input:
columns:
- name: PartitionDate
- name: TransactionID
- name: EventTimestamp
- name: ControlTransaction
  dtype: struct
  columns:
    - name: StoreID
    - name: WorkstationID
    - name: Transaction
      dtype: struct
      columns:
        - name: TransactionID
    - name: TransactionNumber
- name: ControlType
- name: RetailTransaction
  dtype: struct
  columns:
    - name: StoreID
    - name: WorkstationID

Output:
[
PartitionDate,
TransactionID,
EventTimestamp,
ControlTransaction.StoreID,
ControlTransaction.WorkstationID,
ControlTransaction.Transaction.TransactionID,
ControlTransaction.TransactionNumber,
ControlType,
RetailTransaction.StoreID,
RetailTransaction.WorkstationID
]


Just a few changes:

Replace a parent=None parameter with parents=[] to provide a complete list of parent names.
If a column contains nested "columns":

Add its name to a parent list.
Obtain the value path of nested items using recursion.
Add these values to a resulting names.


If a column doesn't contain nested "columns": combine its name with parents and join this list with a . separator.
Return the names.

import yaml

def test(config, parents=[]):
    names = []
    for column in config:
        
        if column.get("dtype") in ["array", "struct"] and "columns" in column:
            cur_parents = parents.copy()
            cur_parents.append(column["name"])
            children = test(column["columns"], cur_parents)
            names.extend(children)

        else:
            value = column["name"]
            value_path = parents + [value]
            names.append(".".join(value_path))

    return names

with open("input.yaml", "r") as inp:
    yaml_conf = yaml.safe_load(inp)

values = test(yaml_conf.get("columns"))

print("[\n{}\n]".format(",\n".join(values)))

Edit: make sure to check the important notes made by @Anthon in the comments and in another answer.

In general it is better to generate YAML output by dumping a datastructure, instead of using print statements. In this case it works but only because the expected output consists of simple scalars. You should IMO also point out that PyYAML only supports YAML 1.1, outdated in 2009.

Thank you, that's a valuable information - I've edited an answer to mention your input.

This should work:
tests = []
test2 = {}

def test(config, parent=None):

    for column in config:
        if "columns" in column:
            new_parent = f"{parent}.{column['name']}" if parent else column['name']
            test(column["columns"], new_parent)
        else:
            name = f"{parent}.{column['name']}" if parent else column['name']
            tests.append(name)

output:
['PartitionDate', 'TransactionID', 'EventTimestamp', 'ControlTransaction.StoreID', 'ControlTransaction.WorkstationID', 'ControlTransaction.Transaction.TransactionID', 'ControlTransaction.TransactionNumber', 'ControlType', 'RetailTransaction.StoreID', 'RetailTransaction.WorkstationID']

You are recursively calling test, but I would not try and look at the parent, just pass
in the list of prefixes that need to be joined by dots.
I also recommend passing in a result list, to collect the resulting strings, that
is generally much easier than trying to capture and combine the return value of
such recursive functions. It is important that you make copies of the prefix (using [:]).
The result can then be dumped with a bit of YAML magic to get the strings,
as well as the opening and closing bracket, on a line of their own.
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

file_in = Path('input.yaml')

def process(d, prefix, result):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        prefix.append(d['name'])
        if 'columns' in d:
            process(d['columns'], prefix[:], result)
        else:
            result.append('.'.join(prefix))
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            process(elem, prefix[:], result)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# force particular output
yaml.width = 10
yaml.default_flow_style = True
yaml.emitter.flow_seq_start = '[\n'
yaml.emitter.flow_seq_end = '\n]'

data = yaml.load(file_in)
result = []
process(data['columns'], prefix=[], result=result)
yaml.dump(result, sys.stdout)

which gives:
[
PartitionDate,
TransactionID,
EventTimestamp,
ControlTransaction.StoreID,
ControlTransaction.WorkstationID,
ControlTransaction.Transaction.TransactionID,
ControlTransaction.TransactionNumber,
ControlType,
RetailTransaction.StoreID,
RetailTransaction.WorkstationID
]

